# Fusion table API select doesn't seem to work "WHERE ROWID > n"

Tags: php, sql, google-fusion-tables

Using the official [fusion tables php api](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) and following [the docs](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select), if I use, for example:

```
$fusionsql = "select ROWID, name, email from $docID WHERE ROWID > 1244";
```

it returns the data for **just** ROWID 1244, but nothing greater. And if it was going to return one row, I'd have expected it to be ROWID 1245.
Other statements work as expected.

As a supplementary bonus, am I just reading [getting started docs](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started#rowDef) wrong, or is there a mistake in the table found by an in-page search of "Inserts a new row into a table"?  It says:

> POST with a specific ROWID, where you pass in data for a new row:

and the example code given is:

```
  INSERT INTO <table_id> (<column_name> {, <column_name>}*) 
    VALUES (<value> {, <value>}*)
```

I thought the ROWID was an internally generated thing? Also, the statement above doesn't seem to actually have the option for a ROWID.

**EDIT:** A workaround is to open the table up in the browser, then manually work out what row number it failed on by cross-referencing other data, then use, for example, `OFFSET 350` in your query.

Obviously, this is a PITA, but it got me going in an emergency. Would still like to know why > fails though.

Thanks.

Comment: How many rows in the table you're using for the query?

Comment: Only 500 or so; but of course as rows have been added and deleted, the ROWID has increased. The first 350 rows went fine but then my php update script timed out, so I just wanted to carry on from where I got to, to finish the last 150 rows.

Comment: The other odd thing is that the ROWID jumps, like:  "99"

   "100"

   "1001"

   "1002"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the API docs you linked to, ROWID can only be used with an equality predicate:

> <row_condition>  Used in the WHERE clause. The syntax is: ROWID =
>   '<string>'
>
> ROWID — Use a row ID that you obtained from a previous SELECT or
>   INSERT. 
>   '<string>' — A text string in quotes. If the string contains
>   quote characters, precede each quote character with a backslash (\).

ROWID is internally generated and has no guaranteed meaning or order. It's also the only way to update or delete an existing row, hence the documentation above.

Comment: OK - thanks for clarifying. It just seemed odd to me that you can't do a >. This means that to search >, I'd have to generate a spare index column?  Also, apologies for the late reply, SO gave me no notification of an answer!

Comment: Think of rowid as a blob with no semantics other than uniqueness. If you want to track insertion order, then you would be better off including a counter or timestamp column and filtering on that basis; then you know exactly what it means.